# Flutter : Shape attribute shows alignment or padding issues with bottom appbar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am working on a project with flutter and it uses the bottom app bar for navigation from the home page. But it shows a little padding issue on the bottom.

[image]

That is, there is a gap between the bottom of the device and the bottom app bar. I need it should be in the shape of the bottom of the device itself. I had implemented notch margin as well as shape attributes, but no change.

Code I used:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      notchMargin: 0,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
        height: 65,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(31, 0, 0, 0),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                  spreadRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(3, 0))
            ]),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            BottomNavItem(
                path: _pageIndex == 0 ? Images.home_active : Images.home,
                title: 'Home',
                isSelected: _pageIndex == 0,
                onTap: () => _setPage(0)),
            BottomNavItem(
                path: _pageIndex == 1 ? Images.offer_active : Images.offer,
                title: 'Benefits',
                isSelected: _pageIndex == 1,
                onTap: () => _setPage(1)),
            BottomNavItem(
                path: _pageIndex == 2 ? Images.cart_active : Images.cart,
                title: 'Cart',
                isSelected: _pageIndex == 2,
                onTap: () {
                  cartController.getCartDetails(true);
                  _setPage(2);
                }),
            BottomNavItem(
                path:
                    _pageIndex == 3 ? Images.orders_active : Images.orders,
                title: 'Orders',
                isSelected: _pageIndex == 3,
                onTap: () => _setPage(3)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Do you have somewhere a `SafeArea` widget above this bottom navigation bar?

Comment: No SafeArea used and code updated in question @PeterKoltai

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use `BottomNavigationBar` instead of `BottomAppBar`? With that there is no extra padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using container alone instead of using BottomAppBar.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works you can add this
inside BottomAppBar color can be updated accordingly

```
surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
```